# Using the Google Maps Javascript API v3, How do I produce the default infoboxes on click?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is what I have so far.

```
function init_map() {
    var places = [
        { name: "Place 1", coords: new google.maps.LatLng(30.728752, -73.995525)},
        { name: "Place 2", coords: new google.maps.LatLng(30.733673, -73.990028)},
        { name: "Place 3", coords: new google.maps.LatLng(40.725778, -73.992249)}
    ]

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: places[0].coords,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    for ( var x=0; x < places.length; x++ ){
        var place = places[x];
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: place.coords,
            title: place.name,
            icon: icon,
            clickable: true,
            infowindow: new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:"hello world"})
        });
        marker.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            marker.infowindow.open(map, marker);
            console.log(marker);
        });
    }
};
```

I'd like to have the default InfoWindow which you'd see when searching for an address on Google Maps appear instead of my own custom window. How is this possible?

Comment: From looking at your code, it's doing that anyway. Just be sure that you don't have any overlapping css styles! As that can screw up your tooltip.

Comment: it actually doesn't. If you create an InfoWindow it expects you to put content in it. I'd like it to have its default google content.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by its default Google content?

Also it might be better for you to create just 1 infowindow object and then share it amongst your markers.